# I am getting" Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. when i am trying to add an object to a scene"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, 3d, jsx, threejs-editor

I am using `threeJS` in react and i am trying to add an object into my scene to have some specific functions that update regularly.

Here is my code for the object:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { useFrame, useThree } from "react-three-fiber";
import * as THREE from "three";

const Actor = () => {
  const meshRef = useRef();
  const { scene } = useThree();

  useEffect(() => {
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.rotateY(Math.PI);

    // Set initial properties and functions
    mesh.instructions = [];
    mesh.target = new THREE.Object3D().copy(mesh, false);
    mesh.targetRadiansOnY = 0;
    mesh.currentRadiansOnY = 0;
    mesh.mass = 0.1;
    mesh.velocity = new THREE.Vector3();
    mesh.angularVelocity = 0.015;
    mesh.topSpeed = 0.05;
    mesh.topAccelleration = 0.0015;
    mesh.accelleration = new THREE.Vector3();
    mesh.currentInstruction = null;
    mesh.gravityForce = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, -0.01, 0.0);

    // Add mesh to the scene
    scene.add(mesh);
    meshRef.current = mesh;

    return () => {
      // Clean up the mesh when the component unmounts
      scene.remove(mesh);
    };
  }, [scene]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update function to consume commands
    const consumeCommands = () => {
      const mesh = meshRef.current;
      if (mesh.currentInstruction) {
        let instruction = mesh.currentInstruction;
        let movementType = instruction["type"];
        let movementValue = instruction["value"];
        let dir = null;
        switch (movementType) {
          case "move_forward":
            dir = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(mesh.target.position, mesh.position);
            dir.setLength(mesh.topAccelleration);
            mesh.applyForce(dir);
            mesh.applyForce(mesh.gravityForce);
            mesh.velocity.add(mesh.accelleration);
            mesh._limitVelocity(mesh.topSpeed);
            mesh.position.add(mesh.velocity);
            mesh._limitGravity();
            mesh.accelleration.multiplyScalar(0.0);
            break;
          case "jump_forward":
            dir = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(mesh.target.position, mesh.position);
            let upForce = new THREE.Vector3(0, (0.012 * (dir.length() / movementValue)), 0);
            dir.setLength(mesh.topAccelleration);
            mesh.applyForce(dir);
            mesh.applyForce(upForce);
            mesh.applyForce(mesh.gravityForce);
            mesh.velocity.add(mesh.accelleration);
            mesh._limitVelocity(mesh.topSpeed);
            mesh.position.add(mesh.velocity);
            mesh._limitGravity();
            mesh.accelleration.multiplyScalar(0.0);
            break;
          case "turn":
            if (movementValue === "turnLeft") {
              mesh.rotateY(mesh.angularVelocity);
              mesh.currentRadiansOnY += mesh.angularVelocity;
            } else {
              mesh.rotateY(-mesh.angularVelocity);
              mesh.currentRadiansOnY += mesh.angularVelocity;
            }
            break;
          default:
            console.log("command not implemented");
            break;
        }
        if (mesh._targetReached(movementType)) {
          mesh._nextAnimation();
        }
      }
    };

    // Set the consumeCommands function as an update function
    useFrame(() => {
      consumeCommands();
    });
  }, []);

  return null; // We don't render anything for this component
};

export default Actor;
```

When i run this code, I get the error Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. I don't know what I am doing wrong. This is my first time using `threeJS` in react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call hooks inside hooks. Which you do in your case.
`useFrame` hook called inside your `useEffect`

You don't need to worry about the mount and unmount states of `useFrame` which is already handled by the library.

> This hook allows you to execute code on every rendered frame, like running effects, updating controls, and so on. You receive the state (same as useThree) and a clock delta. Your callback function will be invoked just before a frame is rendered. When the component unmounts it is unsubscribed automatically from the render-loop.

You just need to remove your second `useEffect` and move everything inside that to out. Directly in the component.